# NSString extension method doesn't call String extension method

Tags: swift, nsstring, extension-methods

I have an extension on `String` that defines `test`.  I also want to be able to get `test`'s functionality from `NSString`.  In the real code `String.test` is more complex.  So rather than re-implementing it for `NSString` I cast `str` to `String` and call `test` on it.  My understanding here is that now `str` is of type `String` and `String.test` will be invoked, returning `String Test`.

However, it seems that `str.test()` winds up calling `NSString.test` and I wind up with unending recursion until the stack overflows.

```
import Foundation

extension NSString {

    func test() -> NSString {
        let str = self as String
        return str.test() as NSString
    }
}

extension String {

    func test() -> String {
        return "String test"
    }
}

let s: NSString = "test"
s.test()
```

Comment: Why would you need NSString when coding in Swift ?

Comment: i have a partially objective-c code base that needs to call this function on NSString's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first function to:

```
func test() -> NSString {
    let str = self as String
    return ("" + str.test()) as NSString
}
```

which should get you going...

then submit a bug report.

HTH

Comment: I wound up having to split it into 3 lines to resolve the bug.

Comment: I think it is not the right way to do "" + str.test() . Because this is an assumption that if you concat "" and str.test() , str.test() will call String version of this method, rather than NSString version. Can you check out my answer below?

Comment: @FatihAksu – All the solutions to working around the *bug* involve persuading the compiler that when calling a function `test` on `str` of type `String` where `test` is defined on both `String` and `NSString` it should pick the method defined on `String`. The types `String` and `NSString` are *different*, if a value of the former happens to wrap a value of the later that should not change how functions are resolved (see @LilyBallard's remarks). Logically the OP's code should work, but it doesn't. My workaround relies on the fact that `+` works between two `String`s and that is [cont...]

Comment: [...cont] sufficient to persuade the compiler to behave. Your workaround introduces a variable to store the result of the `test` call and that also persuades the compiler to behave. Another workaround is to change the OP's code to use `return (str.test1() as String) as NSString`. In short the semantics the compiler picks seem fairly random, the obvious reading of OP's code is that it should work, and the workarounds are just ways of getting the compiler to behave. If the OP did submit a bug report to Apple then it's gone nowhere, the latest compiler still has this same "feature" :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSString {
    func test() -> NSString {
        let str = (self as String).test()
        return str as NSString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually realize it did this, but apparently Swift automatically exposes extension methods you define on `NSString` to `String`. So you can actually delete your `String` version and just use the `NSString` one. Alternatively, if you want to avoid bridging strings into Obj-C just to call your method, you can pull out the implementation into a private global function (rather than an extension method) and call that from both implementations, like so:

```
import Foundation

private func stringTest(_ str: String) -> String {
    return "String test"
}

extension NSString {
    func test() -> NSString {
        return stringTest(self as String) as NSString
    }
}

extension String {
    func test() -> String {
        return stringTest(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: If its the case that Swift exposes the `NSString` extension methods to `String`, then why does `NSString.test` wind up recursively calling `NSString.test` and not `String.test`.

Comment: @AlexBollbach It probably has to do with the fact that `self as String` produces a `String` that's backed internally by an `NSString`, and so it gives precedence to the `NSString` version. This is likely intentional behavior intended to allow the standard library to reimplement `NSString` methods on `String` without doing unnecessary Obj-C bridging (e.g. strings backed by `NSString` call the `NSString` method because it's already Obj-C, strings backed by "native" buffers call the `String` method to avoid bridging into Obj-C).

Comment: And that's why CRD's answer appears to work, because the addition is producing a "native" String instead and so it prefers the Swift implementation. But I wouldn't rely on CRD's solution to work long-term. For example, if Swift learns to short-circuit the addition in the case where the lhs is the empty string then your code would start calling the `NSString` version again.